# Application runs fine on emulator but gives NoClassDefFoundError on device

Tags: android, android-emulator, noclassdeffounderror

I have developed an app and it runs as expected on the emulator, but gives error while I run it in my device(HTC one X). Below is the error as shown in the logcat. There is a method which creates a notification. Error appears when this method `createNotification()` is invoked. Logcat is below:

```
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.TaskStackBuilder
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at com.example.accessibility.Accessibility.createNotification(Accessibility.java:205)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at com.example.accessibility.Accessibility$1.onClick(Accessibility.java:69)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14319)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-09 13:40:13.350: E/AndroidRuntime(5294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me fix this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TaskStackBuilder` is available starting from API level 16 (Android 4.1 otherwise known as Jellybean). Your HTC One X has Android 4.0 on it.

Comment: That was of great help. Is there any other way of implementing TaskStackBuilder to implement in my createNotification() method. But this link says that it is available from 3.0 and newer ..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html

Comment: Yes, you can use the backwards compatiblity library (that's the link you posted in your comment. Instead of using `android.app.TaskStackBuilder`, you should use `android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder` and make sure that you include the appropriate support library in your build. See http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: Thank you so much David.. The link which u suggested really helped and now it's working on my device..

Comment: Done!! I am new to android development and I'm loving it!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @David Wasser TaskStackBuilder was added in API Level 16 (Android 4.1)

You can solve your problem by adding import `android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;` instead of  `import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;`

make sure your app having either v4 / v7 support library added